# Set focus to textbox in nested user control - Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm not sure why this is so hard. I've got a logon form that's nested inside of a content frame in Silverlight 4. When I load the application, it detects if a user has authenticated. If not (obviously not initially) it loads the logon form. Pretty standard stuff...

I can't, for the life of me, set focus on the username textbox. I've tried setting 'istabstop' = false on content controls, I've tried adding an this.Loaded event handler, setting the focus there (including using the htmlpage.plugin.focus method first).. I'm at my wits end [primarily because this should NOT be that hard].

Whatta I gotta do?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what kind of problem you are experiencing here. Its also unclear what exactly is a nested user control , how is that different by setting focus to any other textbox.

Anyway I have the following code in my app and it focuses textbox pretty fine.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBox.Focus());
```

I had an issue when it was attempting to set focus from another thread so dispatcher helps with that.

Provide more code, and investigate where exactly is focus located, instead of your expected location, and try to figure why. Try to move focus around so you can more clearly say what type of textbox doesn't get focus cause they usually do get it.

Comment: Nested User Control would be... one user control inside of another... I have a MainPage.xaml usercontrol. Inside of that, I reference my local application and drop in a <local:LoginPage />. It is on this LoginPage that I try and set focus. I'll give your solution a try and let you know.